# Finding other elements like select, button within div having the same class name in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have multiple divs with the same class name. I was able to retrieve all the divs through the findelements code. But I have a select element within one of the div. I am trying to retrieve the select element within the div.

The HTML code is as below.

**Selenium code I tried.**

```
  IList <IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='className']"));
  foreach (IWebElement widget in elements)
  if(widget.FindElement(By.TagName("select").Enabled)
   ----- Perform sone operations-----
```

The above code is not working. Can anyone suggest solution to identify the select element.

Comment: try this xpath : "//div[@class='className']//select". This will select the div which contains the select tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='className']//select"));
```

will directly get you to the select tag you want to interact with.

If it so happens that this returns more than 1 element, you can further narrow down your search by providing a class or any other attribute to the select tag on your xpath, like so:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='className']//select[contains(@X,'Y')]"));
```

**Where:**
**X** - can be any attribute of that element (id, name, class...)
**Y** - a substring value of X attribute

**Take for example:**
[This](http://automationpractice.com/index.php) page:
[image]

`"//div//ul/li/a"` will give you 57 matches;
`"//div//ul[contains(@class,'sf-menu')]/li/a"` will give you 3 matches;
`"//div//ul[contains(@class,'sf-menu')]/li/a[contains(@title,'Dress')]"` will give you 1 match;

Good luck!